# Wine color vs. quantity

Tags: visible-light, intensity

Looking down at red wine in a glass, if the quantity of wine is doubled, the color darkens. Is there an equation that describes how the color changes as the quantity of wine is increased?

Is it logarithmic, maybe? My interest is in the physics of color and the physics of intensive quantities in general.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_coefficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are searching for the Beer-Lambert Law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law

This will relate the concentration of a transparent colorant to the absorption of light that it creates.

Funny fact, the idea came from a glass of wine, like in your example:

> The law was discovered by Pierre Bouguer before 1729, while looking at
> red wine, during a brief vacation in Alentejo, Portugal.[1]

However, it applies only to perfectly transparent media so if your wine is not completely transparent, scattering should also be accounted for.